# Создание архива через Ruby

Tags: ruby, dll, lib

Можно ли создать архив при помощи библиотеки ZLib?
(Ruby v1.9.2)
Советы использования другой версии Ruby или других библиотек не принимаю.

Задача: Создать архив с паролем и чтение из него.
Помогите примером даже самым базовым, а дальше я сам додумаю что делать.

Comment: @D-side хорошо, я попробовал сделать вопрос чуть подробнее.

Comment: 1. Какая ОС? 2. тэги dll и lib наверное лишние. 3. Я не могу придумать пример, когда имело бы смысл отказаться от использования системного вызова какого-нить  `tar`, имеющегося в системе.

Answer (score 0):

## Нужный вам — нет.

Zlib (которую оборачивает этот модуль) способна только сжимать и распаковывать отдельные потоки (содержимое единичных файлов), а также проверять целостность сжатых данных. Шифрование в ней не реализовано.